# Convert string to list of dates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a list of dates which has been saved to a sql file as a string filed - it has the form `"[datetime.date(2003, 2, 4), datetime.date(2003, 2, 6)]"`. Is there a easy way of converting this from the string to the original format again?

[n.b. all i can think of would be to parse it by regex, but I am hoping that there would be an easier way]

Comment: Do you mean converting from the datetime object to a string?

Comment: no - it is in a string field (i.e. `[datetime.date(2003, 2, 4)...`] is just text) - i want to convert it back to a list of dates.

Comment: Wait so the whole thing is a string like so: `"[datetime.date(2003, 2, 4), datetime.date(2003, 2, 6)]"` ?

Comment: yes - it was previously a list of dates in python, but was saved to the sql as a string - i want to convert back to list of dates

Comment: like an unwanted crazy uncle in thanksgiving, I could hear the sound of `eval` creeping up on this question

Comment: Perhaps you could use the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235606/python-ast-literal-eval-and-datetime

Comment: the correct solution is to fix your upstream data generation process, to avoid parsing Python code. What specific format to use instead depends on your application e.g., `pickle`, `json` may be used in different cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could turn your code into something `ast.literal_eval` can parse and then convert it back into `datetime.date` objects:

```
import ast
import datetime

d = "[datetime.date(2003, 2, 4), datetime.date(2003, 2, 6)]"
dates = [datetime.date(*args) for args in ast.literal_eval(d.replace('datetime.date', ''))]
```

This avoids the potential security problems of `eval` while still being reasonably simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

d = "[datetime.date(2003, 2, 4), datetime.date(2003, 2, 6)]"

reverse_date = lambda x: ','.join(x.split(',')[::-1])
clean_up = lambda x: x.replace('datetime.date(','').replace(')','')

[parse(reverse_date(clean_up(x))) for x in d[1:-1].split('),')]
```

Output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2003, 4, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 2, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, regex really is the right tool for the job - I don't think the following code is too complex, and seems pretty explicit in its intention:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import re

s = "[datetime.date(2003, 2, 4), datetime.date(2003, 2, 6)]"
c = re.compile("datetime.date\((.*?)\)")
date_strings = c.findall(s)
print [parse(date_string).date() for date_string in date_strings]
```

If you don't have access to the `dateutil` module, then you can also roll your own `parse` function:

```
import datetime
import re

def parse(s):
    year, month, day = s.split(', ')
    year, month, day = int(year), int(month), int(day)
    return datetime.date(year, month, day)

s = "[datetime.date(2003, 2, 4), datetime.date(2003, 2, 6)]"
c = re.compile("datetime.date\((.*?)\)")
date_strings = c.findall(s)
print [parse(date_string) for date_string in date_strings]
```

Answer (score 0):

This, but eval is dangerous, so you might want to regex it to check if it is of the format you expect.

```
import re
import datetime
strdates = "[datetime.date(2003, 2, 4), datetime.date(2003, 2, 6)]"
if re.search(r"\[(datetime\.date\(\d{4},\ *\d{1,2},\ *\d{1,2}\),?\ *)+]", strdates):
  dates = eval(strdates)
  for date in dates:
    print date
```

So if you trust your database, you can remove the regex.

Comment: `eval` IS dangerous, so I see no reason why you would suggest it at all

Comment: @TerryA There, updated the warning. That should void your argument.

Comment: Well then that's not really your answer is it. You're basically saying "don't do x, do y, but here's x". Show 'y' :)

Comment: @TerryA Updated the code. But actually the question does not ask about security related stuff. This is one valid application for eval, regardless of the security implications.