# List of Timestamps read as string from CSV File

Tags: python

One of the columns of a CSV file is a list of timestamps. eg.,

```
[Timestamp('2015-01-15 16:37:00'), Timestamp('2016-04-25 16:37:00'), Timestamp('2017-08-20 16:37:00')]
```

When I am reading the CSV, I want this column to be read like a list of timestamps.

I am trying to write an apply function to convert the column which is string of list of timestamps as above to a list of DateTime timestamps using the ast library. However, I get the following error

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x0000023FBDC77748>
```

I have the reproducible code below

```
import ast
x = "[Timestamp('2015-01-15 16:37:00'), Timestamp('2016-04-25 16:37:00'), Timestamp('2017-08-20 16:37:00')]"
y = ast.literal_eval(x)
```

EDIT: As indicated in one of the answers below, I tried  `eval()`

```
x = "[Timestamp('2015-01-15 16:37:00'), Timestamp('2016-04-25.16:37:00'), Timestamp('2017-08-20 16:37:00')]"
y = eval(x)
```

I get the following error:

```
y = eval(x)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Timestamp' is not defined
```

Comment: Is this correct or you just missed the 't' in this line of code? y = as.literal_eval(x)

Comment: Yes, that was a typo I fixed it

Comment: Your second Timestamp also differs between your first and the other two listing: `Timestamp('2016-04-25 16:37:00')` has a space between the date and the time while `Timestamp('2016-04-25.16:37:00')` has a dot. I assume this is a typo as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval` does not allow for the construction of objects (i.e. your Timestamp call).

You could replace it with:

```
y = eval(x)
```

This should work, but is not without disadvantages. Other than that, you could for example do some regex parsing as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235606/python-ast-literal-eval-and-datetime), but that might create some rather lengthy code. Might be worth it, though, depending on your application.

Edit: Your overall code could look like this, including a definition for Timestamp():

```
from datetime import datetime

def Timestamp(timestr): return datetime.strptime(timestr,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

x = "[Timestamp('2015-01-15 16:37:00'), Timestamp('2016-04-25 16:37:00'), Timestamp('2017-08-20 16:37:00')]"
y = eval(x)

print(y)
```

This prints:

> [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 15, 16, 37), datetime.datetime(2016, 4,
>   25, 16, 37), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 20, 16, 37)]

Comment: Note: Be careful when using eval 
for example if you have imported os, if there is a value in the csv of for example `os.system('rm -rf *')`, this could cause your drive to be wiped


See: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval

Comment: I removed the accepted flag as this did not work, even for the code I presented. I get an error.
Please see the edited question.

Comment: I just assumed you had that function defined, since your problem just seemed to be with the "malformed node" part. But you can of course just define it, e.g. like this: `def Timestamp(timestr): return datetime.strptime(timestr,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`. Make sure that you have datetime imported, see edited answer for complete code.